# CSV to customized JSON format in R

Tags: r, json

I want to convert the following data:

```
CERTIFICADO = tibble::tibble(type = "cuar_private_file",
                             title = "Certificado Participacion CC FECHIC 2023 30207",
                             excerpt = "Certificado Participacion CC FECHIC 2023 30207",
                             post_date = "2024-01-21 21:00:00",
                             owners = 1965,
                             attachments = "Certificado_Participacion_CC_FECHIC_2023_30207.pdf",
                             method = "copy")
```

into a JSON file with this format:

```
[
  {
    "type": "cuar_private_file",
    "title": "Certificado Participacion CC FECHIC 2023 30207",
    "excerpt": "Certificado de Participacion de Folio 30207 Cohorte FECHIC año 2023",
    "post_date": "2024-01-21 21:00:00",
    "owners": 
    { "usr": [1965]
    },
    "attachments":
    { "Certificado_Participacion_CC_FECHIC_2023_30207.pdf":
    { "method": "copy"
    }}
  }
]
```

I am using the following code:

```
cat(toJSON(CERTIFICADO, pretty=TRUE), file = 'CERTIFICADO3.json')
```

but this code gives me the following JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "type": "cuar_private_file",
    "title": "Certificado Participacion CC FECHIC 2023 30207",
    "excerpt": "Certificado Participacion CC FECHIC 2023 30207",
    "post_date": "2024-01-21 21:00:00",
    "owners": 1965,
    "attachments": "Certificado_Participacion_CC_FECHIC_2023_30207.pdf",
    "method": "copy"
  }
]
```

What adjustment can I use to the code in order to get the JSON file just as I want? Or is there any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maniupulate the data.frame a bit to get the shape you want

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)
CERTIFICADO %>% 
  mutate(owners = map(owners, ~list(usr=.x)),
         attachments = map2(attachments, method, ~setNames(list(list(method=unbox(.y))), .x)),
         method=NULL) %>% 
  jsonlite::toJSON(pretty=TRUE)
```

Which returns

```
[
  {
    "type": "cuar_private_file",
    "title": "Certificado Participacion CC FECHIC 2023 30207",
    "excerpt": "Certificado Participacion CC FECHIC 2023 30207",
    "post_date": "2024-01-21 21:00:00",
    "owners": {
      "usr": [1965]
    },
    "attachments": {
      "Certificado_Participacion_CC_FECHIC_2023_30207.pdf": {
        "method": "copy"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The secret is to add in few extra lists to get the shape you want.

Comment: `setNames()`! I knew there was a function for it, but just couldn't remember. Makes for a much more elegant way of doing it than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly hack to create the list with `attachment` as the name to `method`:

```r
library(dplyr)

CERTIFICADO %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(owners = list(usr = list(owners)),
         attachments = (function(x) { res <- list(method); names(res) <- attachments; res })(att)) %>%
  select(-method) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  toJSON %>%
  cat
```

```json
{
 "type": [ "cuar_private_file" ],
"title": [ "Certificado Participacion CC FECHIC 2023 30207" ],
"excerpt": [ "Certificado Participacion CC FECHIC 2023 30207" ],
"post_date": [ "2024-01-21 21:00:00" ],
"owners": {
 "usr": [
     1965
]
},
"attachments": {
 "Certificado_Participacion_CC_FECHIC_2023_30207.pdf": "copy"
}
```

I can't seem to make the first objects (`type`, `title`, etc) not come out as arrays.